# Visual Studio Publish throws "MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageDependencies" task failed unexpectedly."

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, publishing

I have a project that I used to deploy as a single executable, but I am no longer able to as the Publish process throws while trying to resolve the nugest. The project builds fine during the publish process and it also runs fine from visual studio.

My publish results:

```
========== Build: 7 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I get a popup with this error:

```
    08/12/2021 21:35:26
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. <---

Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. 

===================
```

And in the Error view I get this:

```
    Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State
Error    MSB4018    The "ResolvePackageDependencies" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentException: Invalid framework version '3.1/win-x64'.
   at NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework.ParseFrameworkNameParts(IFrameworkNameProvider mappings, String[] parts, String& framework, Version& version, String& profile)
   at NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework.ParseFrameworkName(String frameworkName, IFrameworkNameProvider mappings)
   at NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework.Parse(String folderName, IFrameworkNameProvider mappings)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageDependencies.<GetPackageAndFileDefinitions>b__48_5(String tg)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, TSource value, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, TSource value)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageDependencies.<>c__DisplayClass48_1.<GetPackageAndFileDefinitions>b__3(IAssetsLogMessage log)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageDependencies.<GetPackageAndFileDefinitions>g__GetPackageDiagnosticLevel|48_0(LockFileLibrary package)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageDependencies.GetPackageAndFileDefinitions()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageDependencies.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()    TextureEditor    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    195
```

This is the configuration I am trying to build with:
[image]

If interested, the project can be found here: https://github.com/olekristianhomelien/TheAssetEditor

Any ideas what is going wrong?